# Merging Raster data with displaced points vector data

Tags: qgis

I have two data-sets.  One is a point vector of which for respondent confidentiality reasons the points are displaced by 5KM. And then I have the satellite raster data. To account for the displacement error in the vector data I wanted to aggregate the raster data to 5KM resolution before merging the two data-sets. How do I aggregate the raster to 5KM resolution in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is:

- Raster aggregation: Resample your raster to a coarser grid size
- The grid size is fixed value: 5 km

In QGIS Processing toolbox, there is GRASS `r.resamp.stats` tool.

Many resampling tools requires you to set target grid by `row numbers` and `column numbers`, but this tool allows us to `grid size` (as `GRASS GIS7 region cellsize`) instead.

[image]

However, resampling grid size to 5km may not help you to account for corresponding shift of point data (because aggregated 5km cell would not overlap with the 5km-shifted point...see below).

[image]